# Are astrophysical jets at the poles of equal strength?

Tags: black-holes, magnetic-fields, pulsars, relativistic-jets

I know black hole and neutron star can eject subatomic charged particles as astrophysical jet, I am comparing our sun chaotic magnetic field vs those in black hole jet and pulsars. The former ocassionally spits plasma gas at any angle as CME but astrophysical jets only happen at the poles since they have different magnetic field strength and also how they wind I guess but I wonder are the astrophysical jets always similar in power and strength at each of the poles or one can be drastically more powerful than the other?